# Decrypt a GPG file using a batch file

Tags: batch-file, encryption, gnupg

I am decrypting a gpg file using a batch file with the below code.

```
gpg.exe --output test.csv --batch --passphrase-fd 0 --decrypt WSB330TJ.CSTDJIDF.TXT.asc.14.04.22_00.59.gpg
```

Although it does Decrypt the file but I have to enter the passphrase manually.
How can I improve it so that it automatically pick the passphrase and decrypt the file without any manual intervention?
What should I add here?

Comment: Have you tried [gpg-agent](http://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Invoking-GPG_002dAGENT.html#Invoking-GPG_002dAGENT)?

Comment: no, will it be simpler?

Answer (score 6):

You tell GnuPG to read the passphrase from stdin by using `--passphrase-fd 0`. There are different options to read the passphrase, from `man gpg`:

```
   --passphrase-fd n
          Read the passphrase from file descriptor n.  Only  the  first  line
          will  be  read  from  file  descriptor  n.  If you use 0 for n, the
          passphrase will be read from STDIN. This can only be used  if  only
          one passphrase is supplied.

   --passphrase-file file
          Read  the  passphrase  from  file file. Only the first line will be
          read from file file. This can only be used if only  one  passphrase
          is  supplied.  Obviously, a passphrase stored in a file is of ques-
          tionable security if other users can read this file. Don't use this
          option if you can avoid it.

   --passphrase string
          Use  string  as  the  passphrase. This can only be used if only one
          passphrase is supplied. Obviously, this  is  of  very  questionable
          security  on  a multi-user system. Don't use this option if you can
          avoid it.
```

If you use GnuPG 2, remember to use `--batch`, otherwise the passphrase options will be ignored.

If you stored the passphrase in a file, use `--passphrase-file password.txt`, if you want to pass it as a string use `--passphrase "f00b4r"` (both times using appropriate parameter values, of course).

@Thierry noted in the comments that (especially when using Windows) make sure to end the file with a UNIX line feed (`\n` / LN) instead of a Windows line feed + carriage return (`\n\r` / LNRF).

Comment: Not seem to be working either with the file or directly passing the passphrase.

Comment: Have you removed the `--passphrase-fd` parameter? And: "Not working" is no helpful problem description at all. How did you try, what happens, what does not happen?

Comment: gpg.exe --output test.csv --batch --passphrase xyz --decrypt WSB330TJ.CSTDJIDF.TXT.asc.14.04.22_00.59.gpg

Comment: The above command ask for the Passphrase and then decrypt the file

Comment: Does the passphrase contain any special characters of the windows command prompt? You might have to put quotes around it or escape them.

Comment: Jens, still not working, find my described response.

Comment: were you able to fix this problem? I am facing similar problem, any update would really help.

Comment: I've found that when using --passphrase-file with gpg4win that the passphrase file has to have unix \n line delimiters not dos/windows \r\n delimiters.

Answer (score 3):

For myself I had to do *`gpg --batch --passphrase "MyPassword" --decrypt-files C:\PGPFiles\\\*.pgp*.`  Doing it with `--passphrase` not before `--decrypt-files` would always prompt me for the password.  Also as Thierry said when I was using a password file I had to use Notepad++ to convert to unix style `(Edit->EOL->Unix/OSX Format)`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
gpg2 -se --passphrase yourpassword --batch --yes -r user@mydomain.com filename
```